# How does SMOTE create new data from categorical data?

Tags: r

I have used **SMOTE** in R to create new data and this worked fine. When I was doing further researches on how exactly SMOTE works, I couldn't find an answer, how SMOTE handles **categorical** data.

In the paper, an example is shown (page 10) with just numeric values. But I still do not know how SMOTE creates new data from categorical example data.

This is the link to the paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf

Comment: Are you referring to the implementation in the `DMwR` package?

Comment: Hi Julius, yes, I am using SMOTE with the DMwR package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That indeed is an important thing to be aware of. In terms of the paper that you are referring to, Sections 6.1 and 6.2 describe possible procedures for the cases of nominal-continuous and just nominal variables. However, `DMwR` does not use something like that.

---

If you look at the source code of `SMOTE`, you can see that the main work is done by `DMwR:::smote.exs`. I'll now briefly explain the procedure.

The summary is that the order of factor levels matters and that currently there seems to be a bug regarding factor variables which makes things work **oppositely**. That is, if we want to find an observation close to one with a factor level "A", then anything other than "A" is treated as "close" and those with level "A" are treated as "distant". Hence, the more factor variables there are, the fewer levels they have, and the fewer continuous variables there are, the more drastic the effect of this bug should be.

So, unless I'm wrong, the function should not be used with factors.

---

As an example, let's consider the case of `perc.over = 600` with one continuous and one factor variable. We then arrive to `smote.exs` with the sub-data frame corresponding to the undersampled class (say, 50 rows) and proceed as follows.

1. Matrix `T` contains all but the class variables. Columns corresponding to the continuous variables remain unchanged, while factors or characters are **coerced into integers**. In means that the **order of factor levels** is essential.
2. Next we generate 50 * 6 = 300 new observations. We do so by creating 6 new observations (n = 1, ..., 6) for each of the 50 present ones (i = 1, ..., 50).
3. We scale the data by `xd <- scale(T, T[i, ], ranges)` so that `xd` shows deviations from the i-th observation. E.g., for i = 1 we have may have

```
#             [,1]  [,2]
# [1,]  0.00000000  0.00
# [2,] -0.13333333  0.25
# [3,] -0.26666667  0.25
```

meaning that the continuous variable for i = 2,3 is smaller than for i =1, but that the factor levels of i = 2,3 are "higher".

4. Then by running `for (a in nomatr) xd[, a] <- xd[, a] == 0` we ignore most of the information in the second column related to factor level deviations: we set deviations to 1 to those cases that have the same factor level as the i-th observation, and 0 otherwise. (I believe it **should be the opposite**, meaning that it's a **bug**; I'm going to report it.)
5. Then we set `dd <- drop(xd^2 %*% rep(1, ncol(xd)))`, which can be seen as a vector of squared distances for each observation from the i-th one and `kNNs <- order(dd)[2:(k + 1)]` gives the indices of the `k` nearest neighbours. It purposefully is `2:(k + 1)` as the first element should be `i` (distance should be zero). However, the first element actually not always is `i` in this case due to point 4, which confirms a bug.
6. Now we create n-th new observation similar to the i-th one. First we pick one of the nearest neighbours, `neig <- sample(1:k, 1)`. Then `difs <- T[kNNs[neig], ] - T[i, ]` is the component-wise difference between this neighbour and the i-th observation, e.g.,

```
difs
# [1] -0.1 -3.0
```

Meaning that the neighbour has lower values in terms of both variables.

7. New case is constructed by running: `T[i, ] + runif(1) * difs` which is indeed a convex combination between the i-th variable and the neighbour. This line is for the continuous variable(s) only. For the factors we have `c(T[kNNs[neig], a], T[i, a])[1 + round(runif(1), 0)]`, which means that the new observation will have the same factor levels as the i-th observation with 50% chance, and the same as this chosen neighbour with another 50% chance. So, this is a kind of discrete interpolation.

Comment: Thanks Julius! I really appreciate your help on this :)